Smooth tilt a curve between two points
I am making a racetrack. The tilt radius in the middle of the curve should be 43 degrees.
The tilt on the straight is 12 degrees. Ive made a bezier curve that describes the shape that I require for the track, made a small "plank" (0.1mx8m) and used the array (fixed count till it was full) curve > bezier curve.
I am having troubles easing from the 12 degrees to 43 degrees. It does something that I do not expect with the second to last node. But I am trying the following.
Points  1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4 -- 5 -- 6  
degrees 12 18,2 24,4 30,6 36,8  43

Point 1, and 6 are set, how can I get the tilt automatically interpolated between the points. I made a small recording of the situation. At first I wanted to upload it here, but it doesn't allow gifs above 50 megapixels (it is less)
https://imgur.com/a/GDmKXaN

In edit mode with a curve you can select the points you want and do Control Points -> Smooth Curve Tilt.
